# Using DecimalFormat in Java to print 0.0

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting, decimalformat

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");

System.out.println(df.format(180.0)); // prints 180.0
System.out.println(df.format(0.0)); // prints .0 BUT I want 0.0
}
```

How do I change DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0"); constructor parameters so that I can print 0.0???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
System.out.println(df.format(0.0));
```

by using

```
#.0
```

you omit the leading 0 yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`new DecimalFormat("0.0")` will do the trick.